# Userform automatic fillout ID number ans subtract the word infront

Tags: vba, userform

I have created a simple UserForm to enter new equipment details to the Tooling list in the spreadsheet, form works fine except for one little thing, which is New Tool ID.

Basically what I need this for to do is once form is opened/called new Tool ID need to be created, which could be and Alfa numerical set of characters like AA-01234, AA-01235, AA-01236 and so on.

Also, is there a way of posting newly added Tool ID in the MsgBox along with MsgBox "One record added to Customers List. New Customer ID is "

All of my attempts to create this are failing and causing errors, which I really cannot figure out since I am new to VBA and had never used it until now.

Here is my code, Customer ID is TextBox1.

Thanks in advance
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Here is the code working for me but it won't subtract the word out.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Me.TextBox1) > 0 Then
If MsgBox("Tool Name Already Exists.Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
Exit Sub
End If
End If

If TextBox1.Value = "" Or TextBox2.Value = "" Or TextBox4.Value = "" Or TextBox5.Value = "" Or TextBox6.Value = "" Then
If MsgBox("Form is not complete. Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
Exit Sub
End If
End If
Dim ssheet As Worksheet

Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2018")
nr = ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ssheet.Cells(nr, 1) = TextBox1.Value
ssheet.Cells(nr, 2) = TextBox2.Value
ssheet.Cells(nr, 3) = TextBox3.Value
ssheet.Cells(nr, 4) = TextBox4.Value
ssheet.Cells(nr, 5) = TextBox5.Value
ssheet.Cells(nr, 6) = TextBox6.Value
ssheet.Cells(nr, 7) = TextBox7.Value

Call resetForm

End Sub

Sub resetForm()
TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ""
TextBox5.Value = ""
TextBox6.Value = ""
TextBox7.Value = ""
Data_Entry.TextBox1.SetFocus

End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ""
TextBox5.Value = ""
TextBox6.Value = ""
TextBox7.Value = ""
Data_Entry.TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A")) + 1

Me.TextBox3 = Date

End Sub
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A")) + 1
    Me.TextBox3 = Date
    End Sub


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQABC.jpg
```

Comment: I would advise against this since it's a good way to end up accidentally re-using the same ID once you start (eg) moving employees to other sheets.  Instead, store the number in a cell on a (hidden) sheet and increment it for each new employee.

Comment: Hi Tim, It just an example. This is a tracking sheet for a jig and fixture. The number should start with ST2018-0178 and up. It won't be duplicate because end of the year I will move to new tab and start with ST2019-001. I just need a code similar to formula Right (RIGHT(N2,LEN(N2)-3))

Comment: use `split` ... quick example(not fenced for errors) `split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A")),"-")(1) +1`

Comment: I am not sure how to use the split function. Can you please provide me more information or provide me a code for that. Because your code provided in your previous comment it doesn't work. It showing run time error 9

Comment: The split function works by splitting for example a string into multiple strings. Per the [Split Function Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function) the syntax is **Split(expression, [delimiter, [limit, [compare]]])**. The expression is what you want to split eg: "1234-Word". The delimiter is where you want the split to occur eg: "-". The limit is how many strings it will split the expression into eg: 2 will make "1234" and "word". Eg: myVar() = Split("1234-Word", "-", 2) results in myVar(0) storing "1234" and myVar(1) storing "word".